# createLink expression in <g:select> tag

Tags: grails

Grails newbie - I'm trying to create URIs for the value attributes in my select markup (iterating over each object of a domain class). I tried using the createLink tag in my  tag like so:

`<g:select name="project.id" from="${Project.list(sort:'start', order:'desc')}" optionValue="${createLink(controller:'project',action:'show')}/${it.id}" noSelection="['null': 'select project']/>`

Obviously I get a GSP exception, which explains that "/[mycontroller]/[myaction]/null" is not a property of the object.

Is there any other way of constructing these URI's inside a `<g:select>` (e.g.  `<option value="/my/uri/">` without resorting to a loop and constructing the values "manually"?

Comment: Are you sure you need to store whole url as a select value? It's usually done by using javascript, that's getting selected value, and build result url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily done by adding an extra method to Project domain:

```
class Project {
   static transients = ['optionValue']

   String getOptionValue() {
       def g = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean(
'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')
       return g.createLink(controller:'project',action:'show', id: id)
   }

}
```

and using it as:

```
<g:select name="project.id" from="${Project.list(sort:'start', order:'desc')}" optionValue="optionValue" noSelection="['null': 'select project']" />
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Unfortunately I get an error when I run that saying "g is not a property of Project". Where/how is that defined and, more importantly, where can I find some documentation on how to override the built-in GSP tags as you've done?

But thanks for the tip!

Comment: def g = ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext().getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')

Comment: @splix: Cool idea (+1) - never really thought about placing something like that in a domain class.  I would rather use a javascript call to deal with this but it *is* interesting.